# How to add weighting value in graphshortestpath - Matlab

Tags: graph-theory, matlab

Currently I understand the use of `graphshortestpath` in MATLAB. But how can I add weighting value for certain path in the function.

**EDITED** I'm working on routing system using MATLAB and there are certain path I want to block the path. Those block path will have to go to the other shortest path route.

Is there any example for me to refer??

```
W = [.41 .99 .51 .32 .15 .45 .38 .32 .36 .29 .21];
DG = sparse([6 1 2 2 3 4 4 5 5 6 1],[2 6 3 5 4 1 6 3 4 3 5],W);
UG = tril(DG + DG');
h = view(biograph(DG,[],'ShowWeights','on'));
[dist,path,pred] = graphshortestpath(DG,1,6);
set(h.Nodes(path),'Color',[1 0.4 0.4])
edges = getedgesbynodeid(h,get(h.Nodes(path),'ID'));
set(edges,'LineColor',[1 0 0])
set(edges,'LineWidth',1.5)
```

Comment: What do you want to add weights to? The edges? Certain paths?

Comment: For certain path. Sorry for not having that in the question.

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand - how do you want to weight paths? Can you give some examples?

Comment: I have rephrase the question! Hope you understand

Comment: Hmm, if you know where you want to block the path, can't you set that edge weight to be really high?

Comment: but I don't know how to set that! There is no example in the help file

Comment: Well, the first argument to `graphshortestpath` is a (sparse) adjacency matrix - so if you know that you don't want your path to pass through nodes 4 and 13, then set that entry in the matrix to be Inf ...

Comment: Sorry but I really don't understand how to set the entry in the matrix to be Inf..

Comment: If the first argument to `graphshortestpath` is `adjmatrix`, then you just say `adjmatrix(4, 1) = Inf;`. This is really just regular MATLAB syntax.

Comment: Insert the code at??
`W = [.41 .99 .51 .32 .15 .45 .38 .32 .36 .29 .21];

DG = sparse([6 1 2 2 3 4 4 5 5 6 1],[2 6 3 5 4 1 6 3 4 3 5],W);
UG = tril(DG + DG');
h = view(biograph(DG,[],'ShowWeights','on'));
[dist,path,pred] = graphshortestpath(DG,1,6);
set(h.Nodes(path),'Color',[1 0.4 0.4])
edges = getedgesbynodeid(h,get(h.Nodes(path),'ID'));
set(edges,'LineColor',[1 0 0])
set(edges,'LineWidth',1.5)`

Comment: `DG(3, 4) = Inf;` to set the edge between nodes 3 and 4 to infinity. SO will not write your code for you or hold your hand - this will be my last reply unless you have a non-syntax question.

Answer (score 1):

```
% path weights，if you want to block
% one edge，you could set the value very large.
W = [.41 .99 .51 .32 .15 .45 .38 .32 .36 .29 .21];

DG = sparse([6 1 2 2 3 4 4 5 5 6 1],[2 6 3 5 4 1 6 3 4 3 5],W)

DG =
   (4,1)       0.4500
   (6,2)       0.4100
   (2,3)       0.5100
   (5,3)       0.3200
   (6,3)       0.2900
   (3,4)       0.1500
   (5,4)       0.3600
   (1,5)       0.2100
   (2,5)       0.3200
   (1,6)       0.9900
   (4,6)       0.3800


[dist,path,pred] = graphshortestpath(DG,1,6）
%Find the shortest path in the graph from node 1 to node 6.
```